# How can I replace numbers in the remaining columns except the first column using Python?

Tags: python

i want read data using python.

/home/data

a1 1 2 . . .
b3 -1 7 . . .
c5 3 6 . . .
d7 4 5 . . .
e9 5 9 . . .
. . . . . .
. . . . . .

I want to replace the numbers in the remaining columns except the first column.

-2 to -1
3 to 1
4 to 1
5 to 0
6 to 1
7 to 1
8 to 1
9 to 2

```
I would like to change and save the read data as is.

What should I do?

thank you.

I try this code.
```

c=open("/home/data.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
c[:, 1:] = c[:, 1:].replace({-2: -1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2})

```
but error   
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please kindly provide your input data as text and not image, we cannot reproduce it with an image. Also remove the non-relevant code (all imports nor directly needed for the question)

Comment: It looks like you could just use `df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].replace({-2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2})`

Comment: I've corrected the question. thank you